# Is there any property for rtl direction text in pie chart google on IONIC framwork? something like "direction: rtl”?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pie-chart

I'm using Google's Pie Chart in my IONIC app, and I want to display the legend and title in `rtl` direction.

Here is my drawing chart function:

```
drawChart () { // Create the data table.

    var data = new this.googleChartLibrary.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Activity Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');
    data.addRows([
      ['חיים עוזר פ"ת', 8],
      ['ההגנה 25 פ"ת', 8],
      ['ד"ר פון פיקס אור יהודה', 2],

    ]);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new this.googleChartLibrary.visualization
      .PieChart(document.getElementById('pie-chart-div'));

    chart.draw(data, {
      'title': 'סניפים',
      'width': 400,
      'height': 300,

      // Here, have a some option as described below?

      titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 12, bold: true},
      chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%', left: 70, top: 100 },
      is3D: true,
      legend: { position: 'right',  textStyle: { fontSize: 12, bold: true } }

    });
  }
```

In the second argument of the calling to `chart.draw`, there is an object that contains options, I need a specific option that will cause the text to be written from right to left (rtl).

Does anyone know how to configured it?

- [This is the screen shot of the pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaxqB.jpg)
- [This is the desired result - the text should start from right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh1MC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to change your Ionic app to be RTL you can change the `dir` attribute in index.html.

In **index.html** file change:

`<html lang="en" dir="ltr">`

to:

`<html lang="he" dir="rtl">`

If the change in the **index.html** file does not do the trick you can try and manually change the `dir` attribute in the Google pie chart element programmatically as follow:

```
document.getElementsByTagName(<your pie chart tag>)[0].setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
```

For more details about the `options` attribute please look at this link [pie chart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options).

Additionally to make your code clearer and readable I wound recommend to use the following structure:

```
data = ... #you data
options = ... #your options
chart.draw(data, options)
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help.